# how to insert a variable in xml payload data and get the response

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am new in python. I need to get the data based via url. The data is based on a unique number which is in payload. I can't seem to find a way to initiate a variable in "CUSTNO" in payload and iterate it. iterate it.
(I have removed some of the payload data)

```
url = 'url'

payload = "<CHANNELID></CHANNELID>\r\n  </FCDB_HEADER>\r\n  <FCDB_BODY>\r\n    <CUSTOMER>\r\n      " \    
          "<CUSTNO>123456789</CUSTNO>\r\n    </CUSTOMER>\r\n"

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
xml_response = response.text
print(xml_response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below (assuming that you want to change the customer number)

```
url = 'url'

customer_no = 4562

payload = "<CHANNELID></CHANNELID>\r\n  </FCDB_HEADER>\r\n  <FCDB_BODY>\r\n    <CUSTOMER>\r\n      " \    
          "<CUSTNO>{}</CUSTNO>\r\n    </CUSTOMER>\r\n"

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload.format(customer_no), headers=headers)
xml_response = response.text
print(xml_response)
```

Comment: Perfect. It worked, Thanks alot.
Any idea how to change the xml response into python dictionary?

Comment: @AliKhan I am glad to help. Feel free to mark the answer as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really unclear!
Maybe your payload formatting is wrong. Which version of Python are you using?

Try this:

```
payload = '''<CHANNELID></CHANNELID>\r\n  </FCDB_HEADER>\r\n  <FCDB_BODY>\r\n    <CUSTOMER>\r\n       \    
      <CUSTNO>123456789</CUSTNO>\r\n    </CUSTOMER>\r\n'''
```

Comment: I took the payload code from postman. I have deleted some of the data before posting here. I am using 3.7. I just want to make the <CUSTNO> a variable and insert the data with loop. could it be possible?

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot make sense of your question. Improve your question and then maybe someone can help you.